# Rust Lifetime of reference should outlive function

Tags: rust, reference, lifetime

I have a little dummy parser, which uses the same &str during parsing:

```
struct Parser<'a>{
    r: &'a str,
    pos: usize
}

impl<'a, 'b: 'a> Parser<'a>{
    fn new(s: &'b str)->Parser<'a>{
        Parser{r: s, pos:0}
    }
    fn next(&'a self)->Parser<'a>{
        Parser{r: self.r, pos: self.pos + 1}
    }
    fn nnext(&'a self)->Parser<'a>{
        Parser{r: self.r, pos: self.pos + 2}
    }
    fn nnnext(&'a self)->Parser<'a>{
        return self.next().nnext()
    }
}
```

I would use it like this:

```
fn parse(s: &str){
    let parser = Parser::new(s);
    parser.nnnext();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
25 |         return self.next().nnext()
   |                -----------^^^^^^^^
   |                |
   |                returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
   |                temporary value created here
```

The reference is guaranteed to outlive all Parser methods. How must is annotate lifetimes to express this? Especially, why does `nnnext` not compile? It should be clear that the reference outlives `self.next().nnext()` call.

Thank you very much for any assistance.
Hendrik

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using `&'a self`, you're conflating the lifetime of the parser with the lifetime of the string it refers to. There's no reason for that.

If you remove this constraint, there's no problem anymore:

```rust
struct Parser<'a>{
    r: &'a str,
    pos: usize
}

impl<'a> Parser<'a>{
    fn new(s: &'a str)->Parser<'a>{
        Parser{r: s, pos:0}
    }
    fn next(&self)->Parser<'a>{
        Parser{r: self.r, pos: self.pos + 1}
    }
    fn nnext(&self)->Parser<'a>{
        Parser{r: self.r, pos: self.pos + 2}
    }
    fn nnnext(&self)->Parser<'a>{
        return self.next().nnext()
    }
}
```

(I also removed the useless `'b`)

Comment: It works. Honestly, I do not understand why it works. If I use `&'a self` it means, then it means &str has the lifetime 'a?

Comment: When you declare `fn nnext(&'a self) -> Parser<'a>` you basically say the lifetime of self (i.e. the Parser instance) is `'a` which also is the lifetime of the internal `str`. This makes it a problem to drop the instance and returning a value coming from it.

Comment: @Hatatister, the way I think of this is that the lifetime is the `shortest` of the markers.  The problem with `fn next(&'a self)->Parser<'a>` is that the temporaries created in `nnnext` via chaining calls is a shorter lifetime than the `&str` references they contain.  You really want the new instance tied to the lifetime of the `r` field, which is what Denys' solution offers.  That's why it works, and your original code does not.  I hope that clarified.